# Time complexity assignment

Tags: java, time-complexity

I have an assignment in my intro to programming course that I don't understand at all. I've been falling behind because of problems at home. I'm not asking you to do my assignment for me I'm just hoping for some help for a programming boob like me.

The question is this:

```
    Calculate the time complexity in average case for searching, adding, and removing in a

       - unsorted vector
       - sorted vector
       - unsorted singlelinked list
       - sorted singlelinked list
       - hash table

Let n be the number of elements in the datastructure 
and present the solution in a 
table with three rows and five columns.
```

I'm not sure what this even means.. I've read as much as I can about time complexity but I don't understand it.. It's so confusing. I don't know where I would even start.. Remember I'm a novice programmer, as dumb as they come. I did really well last semester but had problems at home at the start of this one so I missed a lot of lectures and the first assignments so now I'm in over my head..

Maybe if someone could give me the answer and the reasoning behind it on a couple of them I could maybe understand it and do the others? I have a hard time learning through theory, examples work best.

Comment: Start with the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: Think about how you would perform each operation yourself, at a detailed level.  Do you have to test all elements?  Can you find the element quicker if the input is sorted?  If `n` is doubled, how does that affect how many operations you must make?  You find [A Beginner’s Guide to Big O Notation](http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity is a formula that describes how the cost of an operation varies related to the number of elements.  It is usually expressed using "big-O" notation, for example *O(1)*  or constant time, *O(n)* where cost relates linearly to n, *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* where cost increases as the square of the size of the input. There can be others involving exponentials or logarithms.  Read up on "Big-O Notation".

You are being asked to evaluate five different data structures, and provide average cost for three different operations on each data structure (hence the table with three rows and five columns).

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is an abstract concept, that allows us to compare the complexity of various algorithms by looking at how many operations are performed in order to handle its inputs. To be precise, the exact number of operations isn't important, the bottom line is, how does the number of operations scale with increasing complexity of inputs.

Generally, the number of inputs is denoted as `n` and the complexity is denoted as `O(p(n))`, with `p(n)` being some kind of expression with `n`. If an algorithm has `O(n)` complexity, it means, that is scales linearly, with every new input, the time needed to run the algorithm increases by the same amount.

If an algorithm has complexity of `O(n^2)` it means, that the amount of operations grows as a square of number of inputs. This goes [on and on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), up to exponencially complex algorithms, that are effectively useless for large enough inputs.

What your professor asks from you is to have a look at the given operations and judge, how are going to scale with increasing size of lists, you are handling. Basically this is done by looking at the algorithm and imagining, what kinds of cycles are going to be necessary. For example, if the task is to pick the first element, the complexity is `O(1)`, meaning that it doesn't depend on the size of input. However, if you want to find a given element in the list, you already need to scan the whole list and this costs you depending on the list size. Hope this gives you a bit of an idea how algorithm complexity works, good luck with your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well there are a few things you have to start with first. Algorithmic complexity has a lot of heavy math behind it and so it is hard for novices to understand, especially if you try to look up Wikipedia definitions or more-formal definitions.

A simple definition is that time-complexity is basically a way to measure how much an operation *costs* to perform. Alternatively, you can also use it to see how long a particular algorithm can take to run.

Complexity is described using what is known as **big-O** notation. You'll usually end up seeing things like `O(1)` and `O(n)`. `n` is usually the number of elements (possibly in a structure) on which the algorithm is operating.

So let's look at a few big-O notations:

- `O(1)`: This means that the operation runs in constant time. What this means is that regardless of the number of elements, the operation always runs in constant time. An example is looking at the first element in a non-empty array (`arr[0]`). This will always run in constant time because you only have to directly look at the very first element in an array.
- `O(n)`: This means that the time required for the operation increases *linearly* with the number of elements. An example is if you have an array of numbers and you want to find the *largest* number. To do this, you will have to, in the worst case, look at *every single* number in the array until you find the largest one. Why is that? This is because you can have a case where the largest number is the *last number* in the array. So you cannot be sure until you have examined *every number* in the array. This is why the cost of this operation is `O(n)`.
- `O(n^2)`: This means that the time required for the operation increases *quadratically* with the number of elements. This usually means that for *each element* in the set of elements, you are running through *the entire set*. So that is `n x n` or `n^2`. A well-known example is the bubble-sort algorithm. In this algorithm you run through and swap adjacent elements to ensure that the array is sorted according to the order you need. The array is sorted when no-more swaps need to be made. So you have multiple passes through the array, which in the worst case is equal to the number of elements in the array.

Now there are certain things in code that you can look at to get a hint to see if the algorithm is `O(n)` or `O(n^2)`.

Single loops are usually `O(n)`, since it means you are iterating over a set of elements once:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Doubly-nested loops are usually `O(n^2)`, since you are iterating over an entire set of elements *for each* element in the set:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Now how does this apply to your homework? I'm not going to give you the answer directly but I will give you enough and more hints to figure it out :). What I wrote above, describing big-O, should also help you. Your homework asks you to apply runtime analyses to different data structures. Well, certain data structures have certain runtime properties based on how they are set up.

For example, in a linked list, the only way you can get to an element in the *middle* of the list, is by starting with the *first* element and then following the `next` pointer until you find the element that you want. Think about that. How many steps would it take for you to find the element that you need? What do you think those steps are related to? Do the number of elements in the list have any bearing on that? How can you represent the cost of this function using big-O notation?

For each datastructure that your teacher has asked you about, try to figure out how they are set up and try to work out manually what each operation (searching, adding, removing) entails. I'm talking about writing the steps out and drawing pictures of the strucutres on paper! This will help you out immensely! Looking at that, you should have enough information to figure out the number of steps required and how it relates to the number of elements in the set.

Using this approach you should be able to solve your homework. Good luck!

Comment: **EDIT**
OK I think I get it some what. Singly linked lists are O(n) on searching and O(1) on adding and removing. Hash tables are all three O(1) right? And vectors I'd say are all O(n).

The only thing I don't get (given that this is correct) is the difference between sorted and unsorted.. If it's sorted, would it be O(1) instead of O(n) on vector? Since it knows exactly where to search for it? And same for linked list search?

Comment: @SamHunters On an unsorted linked-list you can simply add at the head. So what would be the complexity of that? In a sorted linked-list you have to *find* the right place. What would be the complexity of that?